Fetching data from Database Realtime to Model List and use it in Bloc
I don't know how to fetch data to Model List correctly in void without a Stream Builder, because i want create a List and share it to Bloc State, so i can use a Bloc Builder inside multiply screens.
I want see good example how to do it.
I tried to create a Stream void, Future void, but i always got error, because i don't have a snapshot in these voids, but i have a void on Stream Builder.
StreamBuilder(
  stream: filmRef?.onValue,
  builder: (context, snapshot // snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
      var event = snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent; // i can't get event, because i can't get snapshot in voids.
      var snapshot2 = event.snapshot.value;


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
